# Are there alternative ways to execscript on an IE parentwindow in VBA?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-11

I have a VBA macro that opens IE and navigates to a webpage and executes a javascript function on the page. This javascript function accepts a SQL command as an argument that is sent to a database and an object is returned.

This works for most commands, but sometimes the command is very long and IE ends up freezing/crashing with the parentwindow.execscript or parentwindow.eval. I am not sure if the issue is related to the length of the string or some other syntax error in the command, but I am able to run the command successfully manually in console and a valid object is returned in a couple seconds.

Is there some other way to do this through XMLHTTP or maybe some more stable method to call this command through the browser? Example code of what I have is below:

```
dim returnedQuery as variant
dim sqlquery as string
sqlquery = VeryLongPieceofCodeToQueryDatabase
dim ieapp as object
set ieapp = new internetexplorermedium
ieapp.navigate url
call busy(ieapp)
Set returnedQuery = ieapp.document.parentWindow.execScript("javascriptfunction(" & sqlquery & ")")
```

If XMLHTTP is more reliable, would someone be able to direct me to where I can read up about it?

Comment: How long is "very long" ?

Comment: 3328 characters for this specific string but could be longer. Shorter strings have worked using .eval but they were about 100 - 500 characters

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing more about `javascriptfunction()` - possibly it uses Get which in IE has a length limit of 2048 characters I think ? Or as you note there could be a syntax error - no way for us to know though.

Comment: So I shortened the string and was able to get a result, however I also introduced a syntax error in the original SQL string and got an instant failed return, but no freezing. I am guessing there is something going on in the background that is resulting in the IE freezing related to my SQL query that the javascript function can't handle.

Comment: That's quite possible but there's no way for us to help without more details.  Try using the browser's Developer Tools to trace the requests/responses